# Changing all font sizes in Tkinter/Python3

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, tkinter

I would like to change the font size globally in a Python3/Tkinter program.  I've managed to do it in the buttons and labels in the main window, but I also have a messagebox in the program that only displays the default font size.

Comment: The question is for Python 3, but the answer linked for being a duplicate is about Python 2.*. These two languages have different ways to change the font.

Answer (score -1):

Im not certain but I believe you can use ttk to change global font size